# What is the preferred method for serving images

Tags: python, performance, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, blobstore

With the arrival of GAE 1.9.0 we do not need a payed application to use cloudstorage. 
I used to serve images using Google High Performance Image Serving using the blobstore and a get_serving_url.

Example:

https://lh6.ggpht.com/lOghqU2JrYk8M-Aoio8WjMM6mstgZcTP0VzJk79HteVLhnwZy0kqbgVGQZYP8YsoqVNzsu0EBysX16qMJe7H2BsOAr4j=s70

Now I can serve images and other objects using cloudstorage and a default bucket:

```
http://storage.googleapis.com/<app_id>.appspot.com/<folder>/<filename>
```

Example:

https://storage.googleapis.com/jinjacms.appspot.com/energiekantoor/ek_sign.gif

What is the preferred method (cost / performance) besides other cloud storage benefits like folders, acl and metadata and if I do not need the size and crop arguments of get_serving_url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cloud Storage is way cheaper than a BlobStore. This is the only reason to move from BlobStore to Cloud Storage.

UPDATE (June 2014):

Google reduced the prices for both services. Now they cost the same.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a difference between using a blob_key / serving_url and cloudstorage or access the file in the bucket.

Comment: They both cost the same above the 5GB free quota: $0.026/GB per month.

Comment: @Zsolt - Yes, Google changed the pricing. I updated my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, no one else has answered, my knowledge on this topic is about a decade old, not sure how much this will help.  I worked for an outfit that used akamai (my recollection is they were the only provider at the time), which worked well for low-volume images as it provided ideal performance with lower costs.  However, for our newsletter system, we found conversion rates were best when sending the emails over the weekend, however, that meant all customers opened the email at the same time on Monday morning.  The costs for using akamai for that particular use case was at that time prohibitive.  Our alternative was self-hosting, which we did with linux servers behind a F5.  Based on my dated knowledge, I would expect there would be no one-size-fits-all solution and you will end up taking different approaches for your different images depending on expected hit volume, image size, and image importance.  Hope that helps.